# how to use whenAny using reactiveUI

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm new in WPF, trying to implement the application using reactiveUI.

I have added IsToken property in viewmodel
as below

```
public int IsToken
{
    get
    {
        return _isToken;
    }     
    set
    {
        _isToken = value;
        PerformOperation();
    }
}
private int _isToken;

void PerformOperation()
{
}
```

instead of calling `PerformOperation()` in set, want to achieve same using `WhenAny()` of recativeUI.
How do I replace it with `WhenAny`?

Comment: WhenAny works on Tasks and it creates a task when any of the specified Task completes, I can't see it fit in your code for a purpose. please share some more on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Assuming IsToken is implemented in a ReactiveObject or derivative, you'll also want to follow RXUI's property pattern  https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui6-master/docs/overview.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.WhenAny(t => t.IsToken, i => i)
    .Subscribe(_ => PerformOperation());
```

Or more succinctly:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.IsToken)
    .Subscribe(_ => PerformOperation());
```

This will only work if you have property change notification.

Comment: +1 and the final sentence is really important. the easiest way is to be a ReactiveObject and following it's property pattern